# How to fill missing data from a dataframe with another dataframe when having a common key

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, missing-data

I have two dataframe.As a sample please see the bellow.
How can I fill the df[GrossRate]== 0 with the same value from dfB when having the same ProductID

Basically my GrossRate in df should be
150
40
238
32

```
dataA = {'date': ['20210101','20210102','20210103','20210104'],
        'quanitity': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
        'NetRate': ['nan','nan','nan','nan'],
        'GrossRate': [150,0,238,0],
        'ProductID': [9613,7974,1714,5302],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(dataA, columns = ['date', 'quanitity', 'NetRate', 'GrossRate','ProductID' ])

    date  quanitity NetRate  GrossRate  ProductID
0  20210101      22000     nan        150       9613
1  20210102      25000     nan          0       7974
2  20210103      27000     nan        238       1714
3  20210104      35000     nan          0       5302
```

```
dataB = {
        'ProductID': ['9613.T','7974.T','1714.T','5302.T'],
         'GrossRate': [10,40,28,32],
        }

dfB = pd.DataFrame(dataB, columns = ['ProductID', 'GrossRate' ])
dfB.ProductID = dfB.ProductID.str.replace('.T','')

print (dfB)

  ProductID  GrossRate
0      9613         10
1      7974         40
2      1714         28
3      5302         32
```

Comment: There is same number of rows in both DataFrames and same order of values in `roductID` in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this list comprehension:

```
df['GrossRate'] = [x if x != 0 else y for x, y in zip(df['GrossRate'], dfB['GrossRate'])]
```

Comment: does a comma needed between y and df[....  because I am getting an error. thank you

Comment: @Ksaman Edited my code, so sorry, should work now,

Answer (score 1):

If same number of rows and same order in column `ProductID` is not necessary matching by `ProductID`, so use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['GrossRate'] = np.where(df['GrossRate'] == 0, dfB['GrossRate'], df['GrossRate'])

print (df)
       date  quanitity NetRate  GrossRate  ProductID
0  20210101      22000     nan        150       9613
1  20210102      25000     nan         40       7974
2  20210103      27000     nan        238       1714
3  20210104      35000     nan         32       5302
```

If need matching by `ProductID` use:

```
dfB.ProductID = dfB.ProductID.str.replace('.T','').astype(int)

df['GrossRate'] = (np.where(df['GrossRate'] == 0, 
                            df['ProductID'].map(dfB.set_index('ProductID')['GrossRate']),
                            df['GrossRate']))
```